# How to prevent executing a javascript function on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, ssh

I have a local webpage to manage my ssh tunnel on my router and I'm trying to make a realtime sound notification of my ssh tunnel. When it's connected / disconnected, it plays a sound. So far it works well but the problem is that every time I load my web page it plays a sound, I only want it to play a sound when my ssh is either connected / disconnected, I don't want it to play a sound when I load my page even though it meets the condition (connected / disconnected). This is my script:

```
var count = 0; // variable to prevent my function to play sound every second
function sshNotification() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"cgi-bin/check", // CGI script to check whether my ssh is connected / disconnected
        success:function(data) {
            if (data.indexOf("192.168.1.1:1080")>-1) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    var audio = new Audio("on.ogg"); // Play a sound when it's connected
                    audio.play();
                    count = 1;
                };
            }
            else {
                if (count == 1) {
                    var audio = new Audio("off.ogg"); // Play a sound when it's disconnected
                    audio.play();
                    count = 0;
                };
            } 
            setTimeout(sshNotification, 1000);
        }
    });
};
sshNotification();
```

The CGI output looks like this when my ssh is connected:

> 192.168.1.1:1080

And it outputs nothing when my ssh is disconnected.
How can I play a sound notification not on page load but only when my ssh is either connected / disconnected. Sorry if you think my explanation is kinda confusing, feel free to ask which part you don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: Is `if (data.indexOf("192.168.1.1:1080")>-1)` working as you want it to? Always true?

Comment: No, it's not always true, when my ssh gets disconnected, `cgi-bin/check` outputs nothing that's when it triggers the `else` part.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want only detect state change:

```
var count = 0; // variable to prevent my function to play sound every second
var lastState;
function sshNotification() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"cgi-bin/check", // CGI script to check whether my ssh is connected / disconnected
        success:function(data) {
            if (data.indexOf("192.168.1.1:1080")>-1) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    if(lastState !== 'connected') {
                        var audio = new Audio("on.ogg"); // Play a sound when it's connected
                        audio.play();
                        count = 1;                          
                    }
                    lastState = 'connected';
                };
            }
            else {
                if (count == 1) {
                    if(lastState !== 'not_connected') {
                        var audio = new Audio("off.ogg"); // Play a sound when it's disconnected
                        audio.play();
                        count = 0;                      
                    }
                    lastState = 'not_connected';
                };
            } 
            setTimeout(sshNotification, 1000);
        }
    });
};
sshNotification();
```